# Something wrong with Follow Path Object Constraint

Tags: modifiers, rigging, constraints, path

So I just rigged my car model and wanted to do the follow path constraint.
I created a curve that has a shrink wrap modifier and constraint to follow the terrain.
So now when I put a constraint on my car to follow the path, it seems to be floating above the curve/ where the surface is... does anyone know what I did wrong or if there's a fix to this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try zeroing the parent object's position to get rid of that offset:

[image: before--with offset]
[image: after--without offset]

Comment: +1 I've found the best rule of thumb is to make sure that, no matter what the scenario, both the object origin and the curve origin are in the same place. That will remove all possibility of weird issues cropping up.